# no. of determinants that can be formed with distinct non zero real numbers $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},.........,a_{9}$(one or more entries may repeated)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $\left\{\triangle_{1},\triangle_{2},\triangle_{3},..........,\triangle_{k}\right\}$ be the set of third order determinants that can be made with
>
> the distinct non zero real numbers $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},.........,a_{9}$(one or more entries may repeated)
>
> Then which one is Right.
>
> $\bf{Options::}$ $(a)\displaystyle \;\; k=\binom{9}{2}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (b)\;\; k=\binom{9}{2}\cdot 2!\;\; (c)\;\; \bf{at\; least\; one \; \triangle_{i}=0}\;\; (d)\;\; \bf{None}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ As we know that third order determinant contain $3$ rows and $3$ columns.

So total number of third order determinants formed with nine distinct elements is $=9!$

But as we know that $\triangle_{i}=\triangle^{T}_{i}$

So we get total number of $3\times 3$ Determinants is $\displaystyle \frac{9!}{2!}$

Now How can i solve after that, Help me

Thanks

Comment: You also know that three row permutations preserve the determinant, as do three column permutations.

Comment: Colin McLarty I did not understand would you like to explain me, Thanks

Comment: This task makes only sense to me if it is about different determinant values. The determinant itself is a form from $V^n$ into the field, and stays the same.

Comment: Then what does "distinct" but "may repeat" mean? Are there repeatung $a_i$ or not?